# AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'

Tags: python

I'm making a discord bot, i want the bot to give people a role if they react to a message from the bot, but every time i try to run the bot, this pops up in the console: AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_messages' What should i do? I use python. Im new in coding.

This is the code:

```
msg = None
@client.event
async def on_ready(name ="autorole"):
    channel = client.get_channel('*private channel id*')
    global msg
    await client.send_message(channel, "React to me!")
    await client.add_reaction(msg, tennis)
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't use `send_messages` anywhere

Comment: @ForceBru i meant send_message

Comment: @ForceBru U there?

Comment: What's `client`? if it's `discord.py`'s `Client`, then [it doesn't have neither the `send_message` method, nor the `add_reaction` method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#client)

Comment: @ForceBru It is the discord.py's client, so you say i need to install an other module?

Comment: You could probably use [`msg = channel.send("React to me!")`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send) and then [`msg.add_reaction(tennis)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234250/discussion-between-thisbadteamate-and-forcebru).